# Regular Expression with pattern combination in R

Tags: regex, r

Although I have consulted several threads, I cannot get my code to work, maybe someone can help me find a solution here.

I would like to look for files in a directory, which starts with

```
start.contain <- "VP01_SPSG2015_Experimental"   ## beginning of the file name
```

and ends with

```
stop.contain <- ".vmrk"  ## the file extension
```

What pattern do I have to feed to

```
findfile <- list.files(path, pattern = ???)
```

to find my file?

Comment: Perhaps, `findfile <- list.files(path, pattern = paste0("^", start.contain, ".*", stop.contain, "$"))`? Note that in a regex, `.` must be escaped or used in a character class (`[.]`) to be treated as a literal (use `"[.]vmrk"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
start.contain <- "VP01_SPSG2015_Experimental"   ## beginning of the file name
stop.contain <- "[.]vmrk"  ## the file extension
findfile <- list.files(path, pattern = paste0("^", start.contain, ".*", stop.contain, "$"))
```

The `^` means *match at the beginning of the string*, and `$` means *match at the end of the string*. `.*` will match any zero or more characters.

Note that in a regex, `.` must be escaped or used in a character class (`[.]`) to be treated as a literal. Thus, you should use `"[.]vmrk"` or `"\\.vmrk"`.